# ComboBox visiblity in Flex - fails

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, visibility

I have setup a ComboBox named cmbCopyFrom and its visibility is based on the whether a item 'Pricing Zone' was selected from another ComboBox, cmbBoundary, and it sometimes doesn't make the cmbCopyFrom to be visible even though, Pricing zone was selected. Not sure what might be causing this. Any suggestions?

```
 <s:ComboBox id="cmbBoundary"  prompt="Select a Boundary" 
            labelFunction="codeLabel"  /> 

 <s:ComboBox id="cmbCopyFrom"  prompt="Copy From" labelFunction="codeLabelKey" 
 dataProvider="{model.arrOfLOB}" 
 includeInLayout="{model.isCopyFromVisible}" 
 visible="{model.isCopyFromVisible}"  />

  cmbBoundary.addEventListener(IndexChangeEvent.CHANGE,boundarySelected);

  protected function boundarySelected(evt:IndexChangeEvent):void {

   trace("Index change event fired..."+this.cmbBoundary.selectedItem.name);

   if (this.cmbBoundary.selectedItem && this.cmbBoundary.selectedItem.name == "Pricing Zones" ) {

        model.isCopyFromVisible = true;

   }    
   else {

         model.isCopyFromVisible = false;
   }        

}
```

Comment: is model.isCopyFromVisible bindable?  Also; when you say "it sometimes doesn't make the cmbCopyFrom to be visible" I'm not sure what the 'it' is.

Comment: yes the entire class (Model) is bindable.When I select 'Pricing Zones' in cmbBoundary, cmbCopyFrom should be visible.  Occasionally, this scenario fails, where in copyFrom is not visible. Hope its clear now.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the boundarySelected method to make sure that the event is being fired and that the isCopyFromVisible variable is being set properly?